# DELPHI, TADOQuery, TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi

Quero checar o retorno da consulta, mas sempre vem como null.

```
// Inicio consulta
  dm.qryConsMovCx.Close;
  dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Clear;
  dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Add('select SEQ');
  dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Add('from tabela');
  dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Add('where data =:pData');
  dm.qryConsMovCx.Parameters[0].Value := DateToStr(date);
  dm.qryConsMovCx.Open;

  dm.cdsConsMovCx.Close;
  dm.cdsConsMovCx.Params.Clear;
  dm.cdsConsMovCx.Open;
  // Fim consulta, o select está ok.

  if not dm.cdsConsMovCx.IsEmpty then
   begin
     // Não entra nesse if.
   end
   else
   begin
     // trecho
     // Mensagem
   end;
```

Comment: qual banco que esta fazendo essa consulta, pergunto porque você tem que ver se a data esta indo no padrão aceito por ele. Acretido que o dm.cdsConsMovCx.Params.Clear; esta linpando a consulta antes do seu if

Comment: Utilizo oracle, essa estrutura faz parte, mesmo assim retirei e continua sem retornar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o campo no banco de dados for do tipo **Date** ou **DateTime**, você não deve converter o parâmetro para string:
`dm.qryConsMovCx.Parameters[0].Value := DateToStr(date);`
Apenas passe:
`dm.qryConsMovCx.Parameters[0].Value := date;`

E como já comentado, essa parte do código não faz sentido nenhum. Deve ser removida:

```
 dm.cdsConsMovCx.Close;
 dm.cdsConsMovCx.Params.Clear;
 dm.cdsConsMovCx.Open;
```

Answer (score 0):

Qual banco que esta fazendo essa consulta?
pergunto porque você tem que ver se a data esta indo no padrão aceito por ele.

> dm.cdsConsMovCx.Params.Clear;

Acredito que o esta limpando a query antes do seu if;

Comment: Uso o banco Oracle. Essa linha faz parte da estrutura, mas retirei para testar e ainda continua.

Comment: Certo, faz o if antes do Close da linha a cima, de repente esta limpando sua consulta ao fechar; Depois você abre e fecha a query. Mas olha tambem o padrao de data aceita.

Comment: Coloquei, fiz o teste mas ainda continua.

Comment: Se executar essa mesma Query direto no BD ela retorna resultado? O parametro esta recebendo valor?
Do que da para ver no código tudo indica que seja o o fechamento, limpeza de paremetros e reabertura da query que está fazendo ela se perder.
Como está usando um parametro só, sugiro que faça o teste usando ParamByName

Answer (score 0):

Esse seu trecho aqui ate que tudo bem, só deve ficar atento ao formato da data usado, o formato pode variar de banco para banco e com isso você pode não estar trazendo informação alguma, experimente fazer uma busca FULL e validar e se retornar os dados o problema é a condição.
dm.qryConsMovCx.Close;
dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Clear;
dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Add('select SEQ');
dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Add('from tabela');
dm.qryConsMovCx.SQL.Add('where data =:pData');
dm.qryConsMovCx.Parameters[0].Value := DateToStr(date);
dm.qryConsMovCx.Open;

Olhe esse código a seguir que você fez em momento algum o seu client data set recebe a coleção de dados que vieram através da query, e voce usa ele no seu código a partir de então.
dm.cdsConsMovCx.Close;
dm.cdsConsMovCx.Params.Clear;
dm.cdsConsMovCx.Open;

// Fim consulta, o select está ok.

Um outro ponto, ele não vai entrar nesse if pq seu clientdataset não tem registros, esta vazio. voce não atribuiu nada a ele.

if not dm.cdsConsMovCx.IsEmpty then
begin
// Não entra nesse if.
end
else
begin
// trecho
// Mensagem
end;

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).